# MYSQL: find duplicates in a relational field

Tags: mysql

I have a main table, related to another table through `another_table_id` field.

```
id  another_table_id
1   1
2   2
3   2
```

I need to select all rows, that have duplicates (id 2 and 3 of main table)

I tried the following query

```
select * from main_table
group by another_table_id
having count(*) > 1
```

But the query gives me

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'main_table.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Also, this query

```
select * from main_table
group by id, another_table_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Give me an empty dataset, any suggestions, please?

Comment: You can use a simple join for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.another_table_id = x.another_table_id 
            AND y.id <> x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
SELECT * FROM main_table
JOIN another_table ON another_table.id = main_table.
```

This would join the data eliminating the need for the `HAVING` clause

However if you wanted both sets of data use a [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) as this will not join the data

```
SELECT * FROM main_table
UNION 
SELECT * FROM another_table
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's only one table here. Or, rather, we're only concerned with one table here.

Comment: _'I have a main table, related to another table through another_table_id field.'_  2 tables...

Comment: The other table is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Besides, neither of your solutions address the problem at hand.

Comment: Why not. the duplicates are only in the second table joining the tables would eliminate them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158962/discussion-between-michael-staples-and-strawberry).

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of how your proposal satisfies the requirements?